# Add foreign to my table

Tags: mysql

I wanna add foreign key to person_id so when I delete on cascade (person_id) it will also take my address_id and my cv_id to be deleted. Right now my problem is when I delete on my detailpage it only deletes person values but not address and cv both tabels address and cv have a relation with person

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- 04/12/16 16:22:18
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema persons
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema persons
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `persons` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `persons` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `persons`.`address`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `persons`.`address` (
`address_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`address_street` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`address_housenumber` VARCHAR(4) NULL,
`address_zipcode` VARCHAR(6) NULL,
`address_city` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`address_state` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`address_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `persons`.`cv`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `persons`.`cv` (
`cv_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`cv_name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
`cv_path` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
`cv_type` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`cv_id`))
 ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `persons`.`person`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `persons`.`person` (
`person_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`person_firstname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`person_lastname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`person_email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`person_phonenumber` INT(10) NULL,
`person_cv` INT(11) NULL,
`person_address` INT(11) NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`person_id`),
INDEX `address_id_idx` (`person_address` ASC),
INDEX `cv_id_idx` (`person_cv` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `address_id`
FOREIGN KEY (`person_address`)
REFERENCES `persons`.`address` (`address_id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `cv_id`
FOREIGN KEY (`person_cv`)
REFERENCES `persons`.`cv` (`cv_id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION

Looks like you haven't actually saved the changes in phpmyadmin

Comment: This is the code I used to create everything after this I change ON DELETE TO CASCADE.

Answer (score 1):

You've set the foreign keys both to `ON DELETE NO ACTION`, so *no action* is taken on deletion.

If you want the related rows to be deleted when the parent row is deleted, use `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Comment: I added this in my PHpmyadmin so it is on cascade but still not working

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend You not to delete data for consistency.

Make Your app queries to have `deleted = 0`.

Just have "deleted" field on Your table + set `ON DELETE RESTRICT` to prevent data loss in case of accidental delete.

p.s. set `ON UPDATE CASCADE` to keep relation flexible.

But if You insist, find: [Multi-Table Deletes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html)

Comment: I'm giving adequate advice! who has downvoted me, who is that super-puper-smart-guy? (:

Comment: I added the action on delete cascade in my phpmyadmin but it's still not working

Comment: I said to change logic. Not to add delete cascade. Read my answer